# How to set an initial selection for an AJAX driven Select2 box with CakePHP?

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, jquery-select2, cakephp-2.x

I'm using select2 to let user choose stuff from list from ajax.
In adding to db it's working great, but I want  to edit stuff. So I can still select stuff from my select2, but user should see what is the current value of select2.

I've tried to do something with InitSelect, but it didn't work, even after I've just passed data from php.

This is my Select2:

```
    $(".personid").select2({
    ajax: {
        type: "post",
        url: '/' + APP_PATH + '/Projects/find_person.json',
        datatype: 'json',
        quietMillis: '100',
        data: function (term, page) {
            return {
                q: term.toUpperCase(), // wprowadzony ciag znakow - zawsze na uppercase
                page_limit: 10,
            };
        },
        results: function (data, page) {
            var dane = {results: []};
            $.each(data['data'], function (i, item) {
                dane.results.push({
                    id: item['Person']['id'],
                    text: item['Person']['displayName']
                });
            });
            return dane;
        }
    }

});
```

And this is my cake form input:

```
echo $this->Form->input('person_id', array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'value' => $projectcontact['Person']['id'],
    'Placeholder' => 'Wybierz osobę',
    'empty' => 'Wybierz osobę ',
    'class' => 'form-control personid',
    'label' => array(
        'class' => 'col-md-4 control-label',
        'text' => 'Osoba'
    )
));
```

Can anyone help to make Select.js display current Persona name data from database in this?

Answer (score 1):

### With Select2 4.x

With Select2 4.x you're not supposed to use a text `input` element anymore, but a `select` element. Quote from the docs:

> When using Select2 with remote data, the HTML required for the `select` is the same as any other Select2. If you need to provide default selections, you just need to include an `option` for each selection that contains the value and text that should be displayed.
>
> ```
> <select class="js-data-example-ajax">
>     <option value="3620194" selected="selected">select2/select2</option>
> </select>
> ```

**https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax**

So, as described, create a proper `select` input with a single selected `option` element, something along the lines of:

```
echo $this->Form->input('person_id', array(
    'type' => 'select',
    'options' => array(
        $projectcontact['Person']['id'] => $projectcontact['Person']['displayName']
    ),
    'selected' => $projectcontact['Person']['id'],
    'class' => 'form-control personid',
    'label' => array(
        'class' => 'col-md-4 control-label',
        'text' => 'Osoba'
    )
));
```

Additionally you'll have to ensure that `$projectcontact` is being filled with the person according to the possible submitted `person_id` value, otherwise the selected value will not remain when rendering the form after submit.

Normally when creating a `select` element, you'd use a complete list of options, so that the form helper could pick the appropriate option automatically, based on the submitted value. Without such a list, you'll have to read and supply the specific person instead.

Here's some dummy code that demonstrates the priniciple:

```
$personId = $defaultPersonId;
if($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
    $personId = $this->request->data('ModelName.person_id');
    // ...
}

$projectcontact = $this->Person->findById($personId);
$this->set('projectcontact', $projectcontact);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Core Libraries > Helpers > Form > Options for select, checkbox and radio inputs](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options-for-select-checkbox-and-radio-inputs)**
- **[Cookbook > Core Libraries > Helpers > Form > Creating form elements](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#creating-form-elements)**
- **[Cookbook > Models > Retrieving Your Data > find(‘list’)](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-list)**

Comment: I wouldnt use "selected", but "default" :) Otherwise reposting will result in data loss of the just posted value. That is not a nice user experience.

Comment: @mark  I think this will require some additonal foo anyways, no matter if you use `default` or `selected`, like filling `$projectcontact` accordingly to the possibly passed `person_id` value in the request data, otherwise the posted selection probably won't be kept... I'll check that and update my answer.

Comment: Thanks I will try it tommorow. Didin't select2 in v4 was using select? Becouse in my app I'm using older version I think 3.X. This won't be problem?

Comment: @Aksebkit Not sure I understand what you're trying to say, but as far as I know, Select2 was always ment to be used on a `<select>` element, even though it may work on `<input>` elements too in some situations.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work for me. It gives me error: Option 'ajax' is not allowed for Select2 when attached to a <select> element. I think they fixed It in Select2 in version 4. Do you know how to fix that for older version?

Comment: @Aksebkit Looking at the old docs, you'll have to use `initSelect`, please add the code to your question (JS as well as PHP) that you said is supposedly not working, and explain what exactly happens instead of the initial selection being shown.

Comment: I fixed init Select, by sending another ajax with it and returning my data on success, that I'm sending value (ID of person) to controller and It gets me what I want now. I will post answear later. Thanks for helping though.